# Using the WITH RESULT SETS clause to explicitly describe the result set

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I've migrated a SQL Server database from 2012 to 2016 and I've noticed that a stored procedure is working fine on SQL Server 2012, but on 2016, I get this error:

> DATABASE.dbo.proc_DETAILS 6, 9, NULL, 1, NULL, 1
>   Msg 11514, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sys.sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 14]
>   The metadata could not be determined because statement 'Execute(@Query)' in procedure 'proc_DETAILS'  contains dynamic SQL.
>
> Consider using the WITH RESULT SETS clause to explicitly describe the result set.

`proc_DETAILS` stored procedure is executed with

```
Execute(@Query)
```

How do I execute my stored procedure with `WITH RESULT SETS` clause?

Comment: [Using EXECUTE to redefine a single result set](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#m-using-execute-to-redefine-a-single-result-set)

Comment: @Larnu, thanks! Execute isn't different from 'WITH RESULT SETS clause'?

Comment: What do you mean "different"?